# When using a Setter in react how does the callback function argument get named?

Tags: reactjs, callback, setter

I currently have the code snippet below and was wondering how naming conventions work for arguments in a callback function. How is "prevQuestionIndex" related to questionIndex?

```
export default function QuizNavBar({ questions }) {
  const [questionIndex, setQuestionIndex] = useState(0);

  // define event handlers 
 const goBack = () => {
   setQuestionIndex(prevQuestionIndex => prevQuestionIndex - 1)
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you pass a function to the setter, naming of the parameter of the function doesn't matter in terms of performing the operation correctly. The `prevQuestionIndex` in this case is always the previous value of the `questionIndex`. It will behave the same way if you name it `banana` or `fish`.

```js
const goBack = () => {
   setQuestionIndex(banana => banana - 1) //will work just fine, but obviously not that maintainable
 }
```

Comment: Thanks, how does JS know that prevQuestionIndex is referring to questionIndex? I am having a hard time fully understanding how JS knows they are related.

Comment: It is because you are passing the function to `setQuestionIndex`. That is how React knows which state your are setting.

Answer (score 0):

there is no specific naming convention for the previous state value, in my opinion camel casing is correct, I think your example of prevQuestionIndex makes sense as it is related to the previous state value that you used for the useState hook.

Answer (score 0):

Naming of the parameter of the function doesn't matter when you pass to a function.